# Separting borderless buttons on android

Tags: android, button

I am working on android project where I am aligning 2 buttons at the bottom the screen. I am using the borderless theme but I wanted to put a split in between the two buttons two differentiate them.

Below is a screenshot of what I currently have

[image: Button style I currently have]

On things like the default dialog boxes it shows a light grey border like in the below screenshot above the two buttons and in between them, is this a particular theme or is there something I have to do to get this appearance.

[image: Kind of button appearance I am after]

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:background="@color/seperator" />

    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a View between the two buttons with width 1dip

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:text="PLAY"
        />
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/vw"
         android:layout_width="1dip"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
         android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="60dip"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/vw"
        android:text="PLAY"
        />
```